# Clarification of API Pricing Plan

Tags: docusignapi

If paying for an API Pricing plan, it states the below:

"Choose how many documents you need to send each month, starting with 100/month"

I am just looking for some clarification on what will decrement the number of 100 in the above case.

- Is it only when create a brand new envelope?
- If an API call is done to manually resend an existing Envelope with Documents via email, will this decrement the monthly count ?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't Docusign support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, correct, only new envelopes
2. No, it won't. An envelope is an envelope and has a unique identifier. That cannot be decremented because some activity was done on it.